# Make Library Available To All Methods

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a controller method that uses the table library:

```
public function index()
{
.....
$this->load->library('table')
....
```

and another method that generates the table using the table library:

```
function _generateTableHTML($tabledata)
{
....
```

The problem is that table library is only loaded in the index method, so when the `_generateTableHTML()` method is run it errors because it is missing the library.

Should I add `$this->load->library('table')` to the `_generateTableHTML()` method as well so it is loaded twice?  Or is there a better way to load it so that it is available to all/both methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('table');
}
```

You load the library in the constructor so it will be available to all the methods.

Comment: Thanks, I see now that I've done that with my models already, but not constructors.  Thanks again.